# C# SerialPort with Moxa UPort 1100

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

Morning all,

I'm developing a C# WPF application which continuously reads barcodes (about one every minute) from a DATALOGIC scanner (DS4800-1000) and send them to a server which replies with details about that specific barcode. This scanner is connected to a tablet running Windows 8.1 (non RT) through a USB-to-serial converter from MOXA (model UPort 1100).

Whenever a new barcode is read, the DataReceived event is fired and handled with the following method:

```
    private void port1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.log(Log.LogLevel.Info, "MainScreen.port1_DataReceived");
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        String data = "";

        // If the com port has been closed, do nothing
        if (!comport1.IsOpen)
        {
            Log.log(Log.LogLevel.Info, "MainScreen.port1_DataReceived - COM CLOSED");
            data = "COM CLOSED";  // Must be < 16 chars
        }
        else
        {
            // Obtain the number of bytes waiting in the port's buffer
            int bytes = comport1.BytesToRead;

            // Create a byte array buffer to hold the incoming data
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];

            // Read the data from the port and store it in our buffer
            comport1.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);

            data = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
            Log.log(Log.LogLevel.Info, "Data received from barcode scanner number 1: " + data);
        }

        // COM port is handled by a different thread; this.Dispatcher calls the original thread
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            ExtractBarcodeData(data);
        } ));
    }
```

I'm observing a strange behavior: at random times, I see no reaction at all on the application, although the scanner actually reads a new barcode, while I would expect a new DataReceived event as the previous barcodes. Logs say me that the port is actually open and I can also close it using a specific button which closes and reopen it. Here comes the exception (on the Open() call): *A device attached to the system is not functioning*.

I can not reproduce this error in no way, it's totally unpredictable and random! Anyone has got any idea why the DataReceived event is not triggering?

Thanks,
FZ

Answer (score 2):

Most USB-to-serial converters have this problem. They may disappear from the system and appear again. All opened handles at this situation become invalid.

Please, open the Device Manager and verify the power management tab for each USB hubs there. The system should not power off the hub.

Comment: No luck with this option, the problem still exists.
Now I'm introducing the OpenNETCF ports implementation in my software, instead of using SerialPort Microsoft class. I'll let you know if I got additional problems.